# error: failed to get the generic for the primitive "c"

Tags: r

I am unable to install some packages due to an error.
My PC operation system is Windows 10. R studio is the latest version.

Does anyone have any tips about solutions?
What does primitive "c" refer to here?

```
library(vctrs)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘vctrs’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'vctrs', details:
call: state("s1")
error: failed to get the generic for the primitive "c"
```

Comment: http://mtweb.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mus/scratch/rwdavies/R-3.3.1/src/library/methods/src/methods_list_dispatch.c <- it's trying to look up the symbol "c" using R_primitive_generic and not finding anything useful. Probably a bug in the vctrs library? Try updating/reinstalling it maybe.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Primitive <- what primitive means in R